# How to rewrite C-include headername character to lower one?

Tags: bash, sed

I want to lowercase all the header filenames in C-Code, but the "/" gets in the way and I can't get it to convert properly using sed and awk or grep commands.

`#include` statement is one line long, so I can just lowercase this part, but when I use the canonical conversion 's/before/after/', it doesn't seem to convert properly when there is a "/" in the before and after string, indicating a directory. If you try to escape with " I've tried escaping it with "" but it doesn't work. Is there any way to convert it properly?

Comment: The `sed` command `s` can use almost any character as separator, as long as it's the same. `s%pattern%replacement%` works just ad well.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show the (non-working) code and the input you use, the wrong output or the error message you get and the expected output. If you don't want to use a different separator character instead of `/`, you can escape the character as `\/` if it's part of the pattern or replacement.

Comment: What about GNU sed: `sed 's/^#include .*/\L&/' *.c`

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to convert it properly?

Use some different separator.

```
sed 's~before~after~'
```

With GNU sed, you can convert it to lowercase:

```
sed 's~BEFORE~\L&~'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my trial code on GNU.
I've tried to exchange sed's separator, but it doesn't work well.

1. textcode for exchanging the header-letter filename:**test.c**

```
    #include /A/B/INC/HEADER.h
    void main(void)    
    {
      int A,B,C,d,e,f;
     }
```

2. Bash code

```
    #!/bin/bash
    echo "start"
    str1=$(awk "/#include/" test.c)
    echo $str1    ==> #include /A/B/INC/HEADER.h
    str2=$(echo ${str1} | tr 'A-Z' 'a-z') 
    echo $str2    ==> #include /a/b/inc/header.h
    str3='/'
    str4='s/'
    str5='g'
    str6="$str4$str1$str3$str2$str3$str5"
    ==>s/#include /A/B/INC/HEADER.h/#include /a/b/inc/header.h/g
    echo $str6
    sed -e ${str6} test.c >evi  ==> it doesn't work well
```